# My margins in graphs are cutting off my graphs?

Tags: r, bar-chart

Does anyone know how to fix this problem. I hate that my graphs are cut off[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like you've set something in `par` at some point. This is saved between sessions if you save your image (asked when R is closed). So the solution is (likely) to clear `.Rhistory` and `.RData`, and reopening R.

```
unlink('.Rhistory')
unlink('.RData')
rm(list = ls())
save.image()
# Rstudio only:
rstudioapi::restartSession()
# try plotting something
```

Note that this will remove any data you have stored between sessions, so if you have anything important there maybe save it first.